# Anyone help understand this I am missing something after static to print out the console line

Tags: c#

I don't understand how to make this work. What do I print after static to make console.WriteLine work?

```
using System;

class Program
{

    static void ()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hi!");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SayHi();
    }

}
```

Comment: static void SayHi()

Comment: [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-console?view=vs-2019) Might be a good place to start

Answer (score 1):

You need to give your method a name/identifier

`static void ()` will not work. It needs to be `static void NameOfMethod()` instead.

In the case of your example that would be `static void SayHi()`